# Ability to access Skype Full Features in different network connections

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, skype

I'm not proficient with network troubleshooting. I've tried many steps but haven´t been able to resolve this.

I can connect my PC to two different modem-wireless router components. When I'm connected to modem-wireless router #1, I'm able to have a normal Internet connection and full access to Skype features.

When I connect to modem-wireless router #2, I can have the same level of connectivity as with #1, but I can´t access Skype fully. I can log in, I can make phone calls, but I can´t chat, send files nor transmit, and see people's status (not even my own).

I've run `ipconfig /all` in both networks, and this is what I get:

Modem-wireless router #1

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : David-PC
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : 
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 2A-A3-C4-61-30-35
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter ConexÆo local:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : E8-9A-8F-32-E7-33
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter ConexÆo de Rede sem Fio:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 68-A3-C4-61-30-35
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::58b8:85de:e748:6654%10(Preferred) 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.101(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, April 11, 2017 6:48:30 AM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, April 11, 2017 12:46:48 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 292070340
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1E-2B-FE-DD-E8-9A-8F-32-E7-33
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:12e0:0:4004:a080::2
                                       8.8.8.8
                                       8.8.4.4
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 0A-00-27-00-00-10
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::d949:547c:dc0f:5086%16(Preferred) 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 503971879
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1E-2B-FE-DD-E8-9A-8F-32-E7-33
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{12D69EF1-9E35-4DCC-98CD-35345BA3E3C8}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{AAD8A270-BBC2-4EEF-828A-D39B96DE549A}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Modem-wireless router #2:

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : David-PC
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : 
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 2A-A3-C4-61-30-35
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter ConexÆo local:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : E8-9A-8F-32-E7-33
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter ConexÆo de Rede sem Fio:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 68-A3-C4-61-30-35
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::58b8:85de:e748:6654%10(Preferred) 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.101(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, April 11, 2017 10:54:26 AM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, April 11, 2017 12:55:38 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 292070340
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1E-2B-FE-DD-E8-9A-8F-32-E7-33
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:12e0:0:4004:a080::2
                                       8.8.8.8
                                       8.8.4.4
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 0A-00-27-00-00-10
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::d949:547c:dc0f:5086%16(Preferred) 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 503971879
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1E-2B-FE-DD-E8-9A-8F-32-E7-33
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{12D69EF1-9E35-4DCC-98CD-35345BA3E3C8}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{AAD8A270-BBC2-4EEF-828A-D39B96DE549A}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{8B510449-AB1C-4605-9729-B88283F7DAE3}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:9d38:78cf:3060:205:36b1:760(Preferred) 
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::3060:205:36b1:760%13(Preferred) 
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
```

I would like to be able to have the same access to Skype in both networks. You can download the above information for a clearer view here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/k4odif53iw5xoq8/Networks%20IPconfig.xlsx?dl=0

My PC is a Lenovo z470 laptop with Windows 7, x64-bit.

Result of /dumpmsnp on network #2:

```
MSNP: Connection Data (MSNP24):
 * Status: NetStateConnecting.Backoff
 * Server Current: s.gateway.messenger.live.com
 * Server Saved:   s.gateway.messenger.live.com
 * Login: cid-(1680853830051884009)@outlook.com (Token)
 * Skypename: accutestsystems [linked]
 * EPID: 6d62f065-2724-27b1-41fc-adbe71c57993
 * ClientVersion: 0/7.33.0.105//
 * OSVersion: Windows 6.1 Service 
 * Time: TZ: UTC-3, Server: 1492012308, Local: 1492012304
 * Connection: IF: 0 DC: 0 RC: direct
 * B:0 CS:[B:1 S:1] MO:yes CWB:1 Q:0[F:0 I:0] PMN:1
 * Recent connect: s.gateway.messenger.live.com @ 2017-04-12T15:46:38Z
 * Recent connect: msg.skype.com @ 2017-04-11T17:10:56Z
 * Recent connect: msg.skype.com @ 2017-04-11T15:54:29Z
 * Recent connect: msg.skype.com @ 2017-04-11T15:29:04Z
 * Recent connect: co4-s.gateway.messenger.live.com @ 2017-04-11T11:55:07Z
 * Push: None (Unregistered)
```

Result of /dumpmsnp on network #1:

```
MSNP: Connection Data (MSNP24):
 * Status: NetStateConnected
 * Server Current: s.gateway.messenger.live.com
 * Server Saved:   s.gateway.messenger.live.com
 * Login: cid-(1680853830051884009)@outlook.com (Token)
 * Skypename: accutestsystems [linked]
 * EPID: 6d62f065-2724-27b1-41fc-adbe71c57993
 * ClientVersion: 0/7.33.0.105//
 * OSVersion: Windows 6.1 Service 
 * Time: TZ: UTC-3, Server: 1492012521, Local: 1492012517
 * Connection: IF: 0 DC: 3 RC: direct
 * B:0 CS:[B:1 S:1] MO:yes CWB:1 Q:0[F:0 I:0] PMN:1
 * Recent connect: s.gateway.messenger.live.com @ 2017-04-12T15:55:18Z
 * Recent connect: s.gateway.messenger.live.com @ 2017-04-12T15:46:38Z
 * Recent connect: msg.skype.com @ 2017-04-11T17:10:56Z
 * Recent connect: msg.skype.com @ 2017-04-11T15:54:29Z
 * Recent connect: msg.skype.com @ 2017-04-11T15:29:04Z
 * Push: None (Unregistered)
```

Comment: I've tried to access my modem firewall but i can´t seem to find it. I have an Opticom DSLink 279. What should i be changing in it?

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks all right on your PC part from what I can tell with this information.

Would it be possible that a firewall is interfering on the second connection? Blocking some of the ports that skype uses?

Please open a chat with anyone and enter the following "/dumpmsnp".

Please share the output.